# Special characters just broke in the Community Bulletin

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-bulletin

Over on [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) (for tabletop / pen-and-paper RPGs), our Community Bulletin just started looking like this:

[image: Quotation marks aren't being displayed properly]

These were quotation marks and apostrophes a few minutes ago!

The rest of the page, e.g. the question list, seems to be fine - there are apostrophes showing up correctly there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh the joy of converting `StringBuilder`s into Razor views...

Will be fixed as soon as the 2013.9.16.1427 (meta) / 2013.9.16.1014 (sites) builds roll out.