# HTML entities showing in popup tag wiki excerpts

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface, popups

It seems at least quotes `"`, apostrophes `'` and ampersands `&` are not properly decoded in the tag popup.

- `'` displayed as `&#39;`
- `"` displayed as `&quot;`
- `&` displayed as `&amp;`

[image: entities all over]

Comment: This is why we need more smart quotes.

Comment: This bug might be related to [this other bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197133/152515) which affected the Community Bulletin yesterday.

Comment: Localisation. It's always localisation...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dtTep.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the process of localization, moving stuff around, a few `HtmlEncode()` were left in place where they shouldn't have.

They have now been destroyed.

Thanks for reporting - you will see the results in the next build, later today.