# Quotes not escaped properly in Featured on Meta box

Tags: bug, community-bulletin, regression

The Featured on Meta box is improperly escaping quotes.

[image: Screen shot of the Featured on Meta box]

> `&quot;Question closed&quot; notifications experiment results and graduation`

Comment: I was about to post this first...

Comment: This was [reported in 2013 and fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197133/special-characters-just-broke-in-the-community-bulletin). Seems to have arisen again at some point.

Comment: Indeed it's fixed now for me too. A post-mortem explanation would still be good though.

Comment: Not happening for me, I'm on Chrome

Comment: It appears to be fixed now, Firefox, Chrome.

Comment: I've reproduced this *just now* on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I've also reproduced it. It seems to be _double escaped_.

Comment: Yep,I saw it was broken when this was posted, then it appeared correctly when the comments about 'fixed' were made for me too, and now I'm again seeing the broken version.

Comment: Now fixed again...

Comment: I'm moving to leave this open. This may possibly be an issue with all future featured questions that have titles with quotation marks (that they briefly show with improper escaping before changing to be correct).